# Implementing events in C++

Tags: c++, events

After some research on internet for an efficient way to implement events in C++, I found the following methods

- Interface class - Applications can override the virtual functions in the derived class
- Normal Callback mechanism using function pointers
- Delegates using Boost.function
- Signals and slots (as used in Qt)

I am confused on advantages and disadvantages of each of these and when to use anyone of this.
Which is the best method and why?
Is there any other solutions which are better than the ones listed?

Comment: Be more specific about "events".

Comment: I am trying to build some sort of SDK library. The library could give out events to applications. I understand that having an abstract class method or callback is a one-to-one event mechanism. But delegates or signals could enable one-to-many events. Any other adv in using delegates or signals?

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, my vote would be for [Boost Signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/signals2.html) any day.

Boost ensures portability. Of course it integrates nicely with e.g. Boost Asio, Functional, Bind, etc.

Update:

> #### Signals2
>
> This documentation describes a thread-safe variant of the original Boost.Signals library. There have been some changes to the interface to support thread-safety, mostly with respect to automatic connection management. [....]

Boost ensures portability. Of course it integrates nicely with e.g. Boost Asio, Functional, Bind, etc.

boost::signals2::signal sig;

```
sig.connect(&print_sum);
sig.connect(&print_product);
sig.connect(&print_difference);
sig.connect(&print_quotient);

sig(5., 3.);
```

This program will print out the following:

```
The sum is 8
The product is 15
The difference is 2
The quotient is 1.66667
```

---

<sub>sample actions:</sub>

```
void print_sum(float x, float y)
{
  std::cout << "The sum is " << x+y << std::endl;
}

void print_product(float x, float y)
{
  std::cout << "The product is " << x*y << std::endl;
}

void print_difference(float x, float y)
{
  std::cout << "The difference is " << x-y << std::endl;
}

void print_quotient(float x, float y)
{
  std::cout << "The quotient is " << x/y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Why Boost.Signals and not [Boost.Signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/signals2/index.html)?

Comment: @ildjam: no clue :) updating answer

Comment: @sehe : Have you looked at [libtscb](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/libtscb/)? Its [performance](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/libtscb/doc/index.html#performance) is particularly interesting...

Comment: @ildjam: nope, I appreciate the tip. Will look at that sometime this weekend :)

Comment: There is no boost library as I am running the program on an embedded platform. What is the alternate?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [GBL library](http://www.gbresearch.com/gbl)? It has all facilities that you might need (and probably more) for even-driven design. You can build (real) timed and un-timed models with it. It's pure C++, not polluted with macros. It also makes use of C++0x for improved performance. Also if you use C++0x compiler you get lambda functions working as event handlers -- it's very powerful. GBL supports synchronous and asynchronous event handlers, threads, and fibers. It abstracts event flow via signals and ports. With some ingenuity and careful design you can use asynchronous event handlers and significantly improve performance on multicore/multiprocessor systems. It also has a graphical designer and tracer.

Building and maintaining event-driven applications can be very difficult without visualization, designer helps with that a lot. Debugging event-driven applications can also be very difficult, because you no longer have a sequential execution, rather the execution is jumping from one event handler to another, so having an event tracer helps significantly.

Answer (score 0):

First two options are part of the basic C++ standard, with the function callbacks being compatible with C code as well.

The other two options require using boost and Qt respectively.

Advantages/disadvantages is kindof too broad a question, and the answer depends greatly on what you're doing, in what environment and for what purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observer design pattern. Here is an example C++ source of it.
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer/cpp/3